# Mongoose find documents based on subdocument reference value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to grab documents based on subdocuments reference.

I have tried

```
Blog.find({"user.blocked" : false})
```

that query doesn't pull any documents results.

Here are my Schemas

```
const BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: {type: String, trim: true},
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    title: {type: String},
    description: {type: String},
}, {timestamps: true});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    blocked: Boolean,
}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining user as a reference, so you cannot query on fields of other collection. This is one of the differences with relational Databases, you cannot perform a `JOIN`.

Your alternative is to use an aggregation instead of a query, using the `$lookup` operator. You can check about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: I have tried $lookup but I am still getting not the right results. The result I am trying to get are a list of Blogs that has a User with a blocked value of false.